# Macのターミナルでコマンドを打ち込める状態にしたい

Tags: macos, bash

現在、Pythonを学習中の者です。
MacのTerminalでPythonの記法を学習中、意図しない操作をしてしまい、画像の通りのモードに入ってしました。(行った操作は覚えておらず...)
一度ターミナルを閉じて、起動しても同様の画面がでてしまい、コマンドを打ち込めず困っております。もし、解決方法をご存知でしたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「意図しないキーを誤って教えて」と言うのは一体どんなことをしたのでしょうか?可能な限り何をしたのかを正確に伝えないと、的確な情報を早く得ることは難しいでしょう。ご自身の質問は「編集」出来るはずですので、もう少し情報を付け足してください。

Comment: @OOPer さん　ご指摘どうもありがとうございます！編集をいたしました。

Comment: 「(行った操作は覚えておらず...)」では仕方ありませんね。偶然あなたと全く同じ「意図しない操作」をしてしまった方が、うまくこのスレを見つけてくれるよう祈るか、「俺は当てもんは得意や」なんて方が当ててくれるのを気長に待つしかないでしょう。当面の代替回避策ですが、Mac上に別ユーザを作って、その別ユーザでログインすれば、さらのターミナル環境から再度環境構築できるかもしれません。その場合には、どんな設定をしたのか忘れてしまうなんてことがないように…。

Comment: 画面の状態で `Ctrl + C` または単に `Enter` を入力するとどうなりますか？

Comment: @cubick Ctrl + Cで解決しました！このコマンドで実行中のコマンドを終了することができるんですね！どうもありがとうございました！https://qiita.com/akito/items/d09a2d5b36d4cf7bac6d

Comment: 恐らくシェルの設定でおかしな部分があり途中で止まっていたので、`Ctrl  +  C`でその処理を中断すればとりあえずはコマンド入力をすることができます。 / ただし「設定のおかしな部分」を突き止めないと、ターミナルを次回起動した時にまた同じ状態になると思います。 / ホームディレクトリにある`.bashrc`や`.bash_profile`の中身をご自身で確認するか、この質問に内容を追記してみてください (質問は後からでも [編集] できます)。

Answer (score 1):

ターミナルを起動した直後に何かしらが起動され、そのまま戻ってこれなくなっている状態に見えます。とりあえずは<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>で解決しそうです。

おそらく `~/.bash_profile` や `~/.bashrc`、`~/.profile` などの Bash が起動時に読むファイルに何かしらが起動されるコマンドが書かれており、それが停止しない状態になっています。外部のエディタでこれらのファイルを確認し、`#` でコメントアウトした後 Bash が正しく起動するか確かめてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

Terminalアプリケーションを終了（Command+Q）するかPCを再起動する